# set svn:externals to a repository url from command line

Tags: svn, svn-externals, svn-propset

Am trying to set svn externals directly to a repository url from the command line. I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this without checking out a working copy

Thanks
Ipoo Doh

Comment: `propset` with the URL didnt work i take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the command, **svnmucc**. It can do exactly you want. The link is http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html .

according to the link above, the usage is:

**propset** NAME VALUE URL

Set the value of the property NAME on the target URL to VALUE.

**propsetf** NAME FILE URL

Set the value of the property NAME on the target URL to the contents of the file FILE.